# Activity is not launching from BrodcastReciever, when the application is not running

Tags: java, android

I am trying set set an alarm using pending intent from the activity,
Below code works fine when the application is running in foreground or background,
But the activity is not launching from OnReceive when the application is not running.

Creating pending intent and setting alarm in activity,

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlaramReceiver.class);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, pendingIntent);
```

Handling OnReceive event

```
public class AlaramReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), AlaramActivity.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent1.setClassName("mad.todo","mad.todo.notify.AlaramActivity");
        context.startActivity(intent1);
    }
}
```

receiver in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
            android:name=".notify.AlaramReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: What is your device/emulators api level?

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan API level 29 (Android10)

Comment: Your device may have a auto-start blocker on applications.

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan How can I overcome that?

Comment: If it is the case, the device will have that in its settings